# State update on button click doesn't access the latest state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The timeline state is an array which is used to render a list of p tags in the return

I have this function, whenever the buttons for 1 or 2 are clicked, it replaces the Welcome with "You chose 1/2 first" instead of ADDING it to the state, it replaces it.

I know it has something to do with ReactJS states remaining the same in a particular render but I do not know how to solve this.

Minimal, reproducible example -

```js
const App = () => {
    const [timeline, setTimeline] = React.useState([]);
    let timelineTemp = ['Hi'];
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        timelineTemp.push(
            <button key="static" onClick={update}>Update</button>
        );
        setTimeline([...timeline, ...timelineTemp]);
    }, []);
    
    const update = () => {
        setTimeline([...timeline, 'Bye']);
    };
    
    return timeline;
};
    
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I have tried to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to create a deepcopy but that doesn't work since I am rendering JSX elements which can't be stringified and parsed again.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, is `setTimeline` a state setter? If so, why are you storing JSX in the state?

Comment: @M0nst3R, yes `setTimeline` is indeed a state setter. I am storing JSX in the state to render it in the output.

Comment: You should instead conditionally render the JSX based on a flag that you save in the state. It is much simpler to save a simple flag in the state than the entire JSX.

Comment: @M0nst3R the problem with that is I want to have the buttons be inside the timeline rather than at a fixed position, so for example if I were to use flags to render them, they would always be either after the timeline p tags are rendered or before.

but I want the buttons to be in the middle

Comment: Then I would suggest saving a minimal object for each button that has just enough information to render the button (like id, onClick, text, etc...). It is a bad idea to save JSX in the state. This is all ___tangential___ to your problem though.

Comment: In the code you shared, I don't see the state definitions, where is the definition of `timeline` and `setTimeline` for example? Would you be able to provide a running example using the code snippet tool here?

Comment: @M0nst3R I tried for a good 10 minutes but am not able to create a running example, getting a weird syntax error, I have included my state definition though

Comment: Right, that's a [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386097/why-wont-this-snippet-with-async-await-work-here-on-stack-overflow-snippet-edit) in StackOverflow I edited your question with a running example, please edit it to show the problem.

Comment: Actually, why is your component declared as `async`? That's what was causing the snippet bug here.

Comment: And actually, I think I see the problem you're having, it's a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/#:~:text=The%20stale%20closure%20problem%20occurs,way%20to%20update%20the%20state.) problem. You save the buttons in the state with an old click function that only has access to the state at time of definition. If you follow my suggestion to render the buttons fresh instead of saving them in the state, your problem should disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are encountering is a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/#:%7E:text=The%20stale%20closure%20problem%20occurs,way%20to%20update%20the%20state.). You save the buttons as JSX in the state with an old click function that only has access to the state at time of definition. Please read the article shared here for more details on the problem.

The following snippet confirms the issue, when the button is clicked, it tries to add the "Bye" item to the timeline, but it has an old reference to it when it was still empty.

```js
const App = () => {
    const [timeline, setTimeline] = React.useState([]);
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setTimeline([
            ...timeline,
            'Hi',
            <button key="static" onClick={update}>Update</button>
        ]);
    }, []);
    const update = () => setTimeline([...timeline, 'Bye']);
    
    return timeline;
};
    
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The solution I'm proposing here refrains from saving JSX in the state. Instead, you can save an object describing each item of your timeline (`type` and `value` in the following simple example). Then at render time, you would read the different objects and render the appropriate JSX.

To make sure the click callback is not state, I leverage a function generator `onClickGenerator` that, again, looks at the configuration object, and returns a fresh function that has access to the latest state by design.

```js
const App = () => {
    const [timeline, setTimeline] = React.useState([]);
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setTimeline([
            ...timeline,
            { type: 'text', value: 'Hi' }, // store object describing each item
            { type: 'button', value: 'Update' }
        ]);
    }, []);
    const onClickGenerator = (item) => {
        if (item.value === 'Update') // perform check to get appropriate callback
            return () => setTimeline([...timeline, { type: 'text', value: 'Bye' }]);
    };
    
    return timeline.map((item) => { // map your items and render based on type
        const { type, value, callback } = item;
        if (type === 'text')
            return value;
        if (type === 'button')
            return <button key={value} onClick={onClickGenerator(item)}>{value}</button>
    });
};
    
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```